# $y=e^{-x}$ and $y=x$ point of intersection

Tags: functions

How can I find the point of intersection of $y=e^{-x}$ and $y=x$ ?

[Here's the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoX32.png)

Comment: Use numerical methods, there is no closed solution.

Comment: at $x = 0,$ the graph of $y = e^{-x}$ is above the graph of $y = x.$ this is reversed at $x = 1.$ so they must cross some where in $0 < x < 1.$ the fancy name for this intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Amzoti no. I am studying definite integrals and need to find the intersection point in order to find the area starting from x=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this equation can be expressed in terms of the Lambert-W function.

$$ e^{-x} = x $$
$$ 1 = xe^x $$
$$ x = W(1) \approx 0.567$$

Note that the last step is by definition.

Comment: Just as a comment : $W(1)$ is called the $\Omega$ constant (sequence A030178 in OEIS).

Answer (score 1):

First:

There is no closed form for the solution.  You can get an arbitrarily good approximation with root finding.

Have you learned about cobweb diagrams?  That's one of the simplest versions of root finding.  Otherwise, perhaps Newton's method?  I don't want to give too much away (looks like a homework problem), so I'm being vague right now.